# Subdomain Proxy Pass using Cloudflare and nginx

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have my a domain that is managed behind Cloudflare's free tools. I have a subdomain that I want to add named "test" but I want it to point to a second webserver running on my server at port 8183. In Cloudflare DNS portal I have an A record for "test.example.com" that points to my webserver's IP address which is also proxied to hide my webservers actual IP address. All traffic is routed through HTTPS which the certificates are provided by Cloudflare as well.

My nginx default.conf:

```
# Redirect all traffic to HTTPS/443/SSL
server {
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    listen 80;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# example.com
server {
    server_name example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    index index.php index.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/origincert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.key;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /website;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

# test.example.com -> proxy pass to 8183
server {
    server_name test.example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/origincert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://MY_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:8183;
    }
}
```

However when I navigate to `https://test.example.com` or `http` then I am simply rerouted to `https://example.com`. I have an Origin Server Certificates installed on my server which has `example.com, *.example.com, and test.example.com` installed and used.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with DNS records. Check them and make sure that there aren't records like `*.example.com -> example.com`
Make sure that the `test` subdomain points directly to your server's IP address, same as `example.com`.

So if you have
`example.com -> 1.2.3.4`
make sure you also have
`test.example.com -> 1.2.3.4.` and not `test.example.com -> example.com`